# find time taken by user to solve math problems

Tags: python, math, random, time

I need to write a program that will ask simple random addition problems and find the time it takes the user to solve this. The program should keep on asking math problems until told to stop. It should find the average of correct answers, the fastest answer and the average answer time.
I started to write the program but it is not working, so I don't even know how to continue. I cannot get it to print the math problems. can you please show me what I am doing wrong and help me with how to find fastest question and average time per question as well as average for how many questions are correct?
here is what the problem should look like when run:

```
>>> Math()
Are you ready? no
Okay fine
>>> Math()
Are you ready? yes 
0+5=5
4 + 9 = 13
3 + 2 = 89 1+5=6
3+3=9
1+7=8
7 + 7 = 14 5+4=9
1 + 8 = stop
You answered 75% problems correctly
Your average answer time is 1.4388 seconds
Your fastest answer time is 1.2247 seconds
```

this is what I have:

```
def fastMath():
ready=input('Are you ready?')
num1 = int(random.randint(0,10))
num2 = int(random.randint(0,10))
operator = '+'
math = ((num1)+ operator +(num2))
if ready == 'no':
    print ('Okay fine')
else:
    start=time.clock
    print (math)
    while math = true:
        print (math)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously homework, so I will not provide you will full code but just give some pointers as to what you are doing wrong.

- you have to `import time` if you want to use functions from that module
- `clock` is a function, so you have to invoke it, like `clock()` instead of just `clock`
- not sure, but I think `time.time()` works better than `time.clock()`
- you are asking the same math question over and over again; move the part with `num1 = ...` up to `math = ...` into a function, returning the equation as a string *and* the correct result
- `while math = true:` does not make any sense. `math` is a string. You have to get the user's `input` and compare it to the expected result
- create two integer variables, `total_questions` and `correct_answers`, then use those to calculate the percentage
- create a list holding the time that passed for each answer. Use `min` to get the fastest time, and `sum` and `len` for the average.

Comment: One more piece of advice: Look at the error you get when you try to run your program, and try to understand it-- start with the last line. Fix it and try again: You'll get another error (your program has several syntax and type errors), but eventually it'll run and you can start focusing on getting it to work _correctly_.

Comment: how can I make a loop that will keep asking math problems until is told to stop?

Comment: @April: In fact this is depending on the 'termination condition'. If you want to ask a specific number of questions you could use a for-loop as shown in my answer below. If you want to stop after a certain time you could use a while-loop which checks the elpased time and breaks after a maximum time is exceeded. Interrupting the user while answering questions would be kind of difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar a few weeks ago to do some 'brain callisthenics' (by writing code and solving the given math questions). I just added a few more lines to my previous code and tidied up a bit to fulfill your requirements.

However, I am absolutely not sure if everything works like expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import time

from random import randint


class MathQuestions:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = None
        self.question_status = list()
        self.question_durations = list()

        self.ask_num_questions()


    def ask_num_questions(self):
        '''Ask user how many questions should be solved'''

        num_questions = input('How many questions should I ask? ')
        try:
            num_questions = int(num_questions)
            self.handle_questions(num_questions)
        except ValueError:
            print('This is not a valid number.')
            self.ask_num_questions()


    def ask_user_ready(self):
        '''Ask user if he is ready or not'''

        user_ready = input('Are you ready? (yes / [no]) ')
        if user_ready != 'yes':
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            return(time.time())


    def handle_questions(self, num):
        '''Generate as many questions as wanted and get start time'''

        self.start_time = time.time()

        for n in range(num):
            self.ask_question()

        self.stop_questions(self.start_time)


    def ask_question(self):
        '''Ask a question by gernerating two random integers'''

        operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
        op = operators[randint(0, len(operators)-1)]

        num1 = randint(0, 100)
        if op == '/':
            num2 = randint(1, 100)
        else:
            num2 = randint(0, 10)

        start_time = time.time()

        answer = input('{} {} {} = '.format(num1, op, num2))
        self.question_durations.append(time.time() - start_time)

        if op == '+':
            question = num1 + num2
        elif op == '-':
            question = num1 - num2
        elif op == '*':
            question = num1 * num2
        elif op == '/':
            question = num1 / num2

        try:
            answer = float(answer)
            if answer == question:
                status = True
            else:
                status = False
        except ValueError:
            status = False

        self.question_status.append(status)


    def stop_questions(self, start_time):
        '''Stop questioning and do some user statistics'''

        stop_time = time.time() - self.start_time

        avg_duration = sum(self.question_durations) / len(self.question_durations)
        min_duration = min(self.question_durations)
        max_duration = max(self.question_durations)

        percentage_correct = (self.question_status.count(1) / len(self.question_status)) * 100

        print('Your average duration per answer is: {:3.3f} seconds'.format(avg_duration))
        print('Your minimum duration was: {:3.3f} seconds'.format(min_duration))
        print('Your maximum duration was: {:3.3f} seconds'.format(max_duration))

        print('You answered {:3.3f} percent of all questions correct.\n'.format(percentage_correct))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = MathQuestions()
```